# SVN - should I check out from trunk or from the folder above trunk?

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

Apparently I still don't get what the proper way to use svn is. When I do a fresh checkout, should I check out from the trunk folder or from the folder just above it? If I have to checkout from the higher level folder, how can I easily switch branches without pointing my IDE to the new source files?

Comment: I do not checkout higher level folders. Only the folders (trunk, branches) that I need. What should be the benefid form checking out more you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your workflow but the more common workflow is to check out the trunk and, when you need to work on a different feature, you create a branch and switch your local working copy to that branch. That way you use less hard disk space; if you checkout one directory above trunk, you will get a copy of trunk and all your existent branches, which can take up quite a lot of hard disk space depending on the number of branches and the size of your code base.

Answer (score 1):

What you check out is entirely up to you, but to have a working copy of trunk on your drive just check out trunk. There is no *need* to check out the folder above or indeed the root. Unlike some other source control systems, svn allows you to [check out](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) only the levels you need.

With regards to branches, a common approach is to have a single working copy and [switch](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-switch-1) between trunk and branches as required.

Personally, I prefer to check out (seperately) both trunk and branches, as I often have more than one branch on the go and sometimes need to work directly in trunk too, concurrently (small company, large workload). This approach would logically work quite well if "The Branch-When-Needed system" is in use, as detailed in *[Subversion Best Practices](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html)*.